# For which $a , b , c$ $\sum \frac{a^n}{(\log n)^c n^b}$ would be divergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> $$\sum \frac{a^n}{(\log n)^c n^b}$$

Can anyone please explain me what will be the range of $a , b , c$ for the divergence of that series?

My TrY : I think when $|a| > 1$ then for any $b ,c $ the series will be divergent and $|a| < 1$ then for any $b ,c $ the series will be convergent. But I have NO idea about the case when $|a| = 1$.

Please correct me If I went wrong anywhere.

Thank You in Advace.

Comment: For $a=1$, the [Integral Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence)  $$ \int_{2}^{\infty}\left(\log(x)\right)^{-c}\,x^{-b}\,dx=\left(\log(2)\right)^{1-c}\,E_c\left((b-1)\log2\right) $$ Where $E_{n}(x)$ is the [Exponential Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), shows: $b\gt1$ convergent, $b\lt1$ divergent. And for $b=1$ we have $c\gt1$ convergent, and $c\le1$ divergent.

Comment: @cmi Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

For the case $a=1$ refer to [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

For the case $a=-1$ refer to alternating series test.

Comment: Yea I thought it. But It is not necessary condition. We need some necessary condition to show divergence.@gimusi

Comment: You can also use the comparison test, noting the slower growth of $log(n)$ compared to $n$

Comment: @cmi Cauchy is a necessary and sufficient condition. Alternating series test is a sufficient condition.

Comment: Okkk then how would you check when $a = -1$?@gimusi

Comment: For a=-1 let consider all the possible subcases. For example for $b,c<0$ the series converges by alternating series test. For $b>0, c<0$ it diverges since $\lim a_n \not \to 0$, and so on.

Comment: @cmi Sorry in the last I mean "For b<0 and c>0..."

Comment: Can   you write an exhaustive answer?@gimusi

Comment: actually I am not so sure about the case when $a<-1$ ? Can you please write an exhaustive answer.

Comment: @cmi When $a<-1$ then $\frac{a^n}{(\log n)^c n^b}\not \to 0$, consider for example $a=-2$.